# C# Determine value of a custom string on a parent form

Tags: c#

I have a custom TextBox on a standard Windows Form.  In OnLeave() of the TextBox, I am trying to find out the value of a particular custom string property added to the form in its constructor;

Form constructor;

```
public partial class FormName : Form
{
    public string psTableName { get; set; }
```

TextBox OnLeave Method;

```
    protected override void OnLeave(EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!Convert.ToDouble(this.Text).Equals(this.rnOrigValue))
            {
```

Inside the if statement above, I am trying to find;

```
This.FindForm().psTableName
```

I have tried looping through the controls with;

```
foreach (Control loObject in this.FindForm().Controls)
{
// Code here
}
```

But that only retrieves the TextBox, Labels, etc.   However can I find the value of psTableName?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Devin, this kind of code solves your problem:

```
(this.FindForm() as FormName).psTablename
```

But I think that this is not what you really want. In fact, this works only when your custom TextBox is used in FormName, or in a Form derived from FormName, since `this.FindForm() as FormName` would return null in every other situation. This is a strong limitation for a control, and I'd try to avoid it.

For instance you could add a psTableName property to your control that could be passed by the form, but you should be careful to update it everytime the property in the Form changes (maybe with an ad hoc event).

Otherwise you should use reflection in this way:

```
string s;
Form parentForm = FindForm();
PropertyInfo pi = parentForm.GetType().GetProperty("psTableName");
if (pi != null)
    s = (string)pi.GetValue(parentForm, null);
```

Comment: Thanks Francesco, this is what I needed.  I did try using (this.FindForm() as FormName).psTablename, but it would not work for me.

Answer (score 4):

First, a string is not a control and therefore won't be returned by `FindForm().Controls`

Since it's a public member, can't you just do:

`(this.FindForm() as FormName).psTablename`

I would check for null, first, but you get the idea.

Comment: You're right. Obviously it would work only if the control is in an instance of FormName, or of a class derived from it.

Answer (score 2):

You can do so like this:

```
FormName form = this.FindForm() as FormName;
if (form != null)
{
    string psTableName = form.psTablename;
}
```

However, that's typically bad practice.  Usually, you don't want a UserControl to assume that it's parent form is of a particular type.  It would be better to make a public table name property on the control that can be set by the form.

The Controls collection contains a list of all the child controls for the form.  Nothing will show up in that collection unless your code specifically adds it to that collection by calling `Controls.Add`.  You can see the code where that is being done for all of your controls by looking at the designer-generated code file.

You mentioned the Form's constructor, but you didn't show it.

Also, you keep using the `this` keyword which is unnecessary unless you have a naming conflict.  When there is no naming conflict, using the `this` keyword is optional.  So for instance, you could simply say `FindForm().Controls` or `Convert.ToDouble(Text).Equals(rnOrigValue)`.

Comment: Mmmmh. Devin got it right, OnLeave is a method defined in the OP's custom TextBox, not in the Form containing it. BTW if it were the method associated with the Leave event of the TextBox, it wouldn't have been overridden, and it would have got the sender among the arguments (something like `private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)`).

Answer (score 0):

Does this achieve what you are looking for?

```
protected override void OnLeave(EventArgs e)
{
    string x = this.psTableName;
}
```

Comment: Bah!  SteveDog beat me to it. :)